# jQuery UI slider - Number of steps to be 12, with different numerical jumps based upon max/min variables

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, uislider, jquery-ui-slider

I would like the number of steps to be 12 in total, but for the equal distance interval to be determined upon the min and the max variables.  Any help or a point in the right direction in achieving this would be greatly appreciated.

Below is my Javascript/jQuery code:

```
// Have the user input their medical bill amount
var originalAmount = prompt('What is the amount of your medical bill?');
console.log(originalAmount);

// Take off 20% of the medical bill for a discount
var discountAmount = originalAmount * .20;
console.log('Your discount is 20%, which is ' + discountAmount + ' in savings.');

// Declare what the new amount owed is after taking the discount off
var newAmount = originalAmount - discountAmount;
console.log('Your new amount owed for your bill is ' + newAmount + ' .');

// First step-payment is calculated by dividing the amount of the bill into twelve months
var firstStep =  Math.round(newAmount / 12 *100)/100;

// Last step-payment is calculated by dividing the amount of the bill into two months
var lastStep = Math.round(newAmount / 2 *100)/100;

// Calculate middle steps to be divisible by 12 months
var middleSteps = Math.round(newAmount / 12 *100)/100;

// jQuery function for the slider
$(function() {
  $( "#slider" ).slider({
      min: firstStep,
      max: lastStep,
      step: middleSteps,
      slide: function( event, ui ) {
        $( "#amount" ).val( "$" + ui.value );
      }
  });
  $( "#amount" ).val( "$" + $( "#slider" ).slider( "value" ) );
});
```

Comment: AFAIK you can't do so. jquery UI slider doesn't allow variable step. So you have to modify that plugin or use another one. _BTW_: [`min/max`](http://api.jqueryui.com/slider/#option-max) options are related to the slider's **value**, not step.

Comment: Do you want to show what each payment would be over a 12 month period?

Comment: @wahwahwah That is correct.

Comment: @hindmost Would you have any recommendations on a different plugin or how to modify the current one?

Comment: @KatieReed - I think you might just have the settings wrong on the ui slider. Or I could be misunderstanding what you want. [Please take a look at this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bgc7xfq6/33/)

Comment: @wahwahwah The idea is that someone would input their medical bill amount, and after a discount is taken off, the user now has a new amount to be paid. The user then will have the option to choose how much they would like to pay a month until the amount is fully paid. For example, if someone inputs their medical bill to be $1000, after a 20% discount it would become $800, and then I want 800 to be divided into 12 ticks on a slider with each value divided by the number of months. The first tick would be $800 for one month, while the last tick would be approx. $66 for twelve months.

Answer (score 0):

From the comments, I think you're trying to make the `ui slider` itself do to much. You really only need to set it from 1-12, set the step to 1, and then run your monthly payment calcs inside your slider's `slide()` method.

Here's an example [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bgc7xfq6/77/).

And the code...

*[note - this example does not contain any validation logic you'll likely need]*

**jQuery / Javascript:**

```
// setup your variables / initialize slider
var bill = 0,
    discount = 0,
    newBill = 0,
    reqDist = 0,
    sliderIndex = 0;

var slide = $("#slider").slider({
    value: 1,
    min: 0,
    max: 12,
    step: 1,
    slide: function (event, ui) {
        sliderIndex = ui.value;
        $('#month').text(sliderIndex);
        reqDist = calcDistribution(newBill, sliderIndex);
        $('#amount').val("$" + reqDist);
    }
});


// disable until user adds a current bill
$(function () {
    slide.slider('disable');
});


$('#go').click(function () {

    // turn the slider on
    slide.slider('enable');
    // get the entered value
    bill = $('#medBill').val();

    // discount
    discount = calcDiscount(bill);
    $('#discount').text("$" + discount);

    // new bill
    newBill = bill - discount;
    $('#newBill').text("$" + newBill);


    // one month
    $('#month').text(1);
    $('#amount').val("$" + newBill);
});



// helper functions
function calcDiscount(val) {
    return val * 0.20;
}

function calcDistribution(value, period){
    return Math.round(value / period);
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id="container">
    <div>
        <p>
            <label>What is your current medical bill?</label>
            <input type="input" id="medBill" value="800" />
            <button id="go">Enter</button>
        </p>
    </div>
    <div>
        <p>
            <label>Discount:</label>
            <label class="result" id="discount"></label>
        </p>
        <p>
            <label>New payment amount:</label>
            <label class="result" id="newBill"></label>
        </p>
    </div>
    <div>
        <p>
            <label for="amount">Current <em class="result" id="month">0</em> month payment amount:</label>
            <input type="text" id="amount" style="border:0; color:#f6931f; font weight:bold;" readonly />
        </p>
    </div>
    <div id="slider"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#slider {
    width: 600px;
}
.result {
    color: darkgreen;
}
#container {
    padding: 20px;
}
```